# how to trigger ItemsControl.GetContainerForItemOverride for unit test

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, controls

Im writing some unit tests and I have the following controls defined.

```
public class MyItemsControl : ItemsControl
{
    public DependencyObject ContainerFromIndex(int index)
    {
        return (FrameworkElement)ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);

    }

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
     {
         return new MyControl();
     }
 }

 public class MyControl : Control { }
```

In my unit test, I am creating a window with an itemsControl and I want the GetContainerForItemOverride() method to get called so everytime I add an item to the ItemsControl, a container for it is created. But I cant figure out how to trigger it.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    Window window = new Window();

    var model = new ViewModel();

    MyItemsControl itemsControl = new MyItemsControl();

    window.Content = itemsControl;
    itemsControl.Items.Add(model);

    var container = itemsControl.ContainerFromDataContext(slideModel);  
}
```

I thought `itemsControl.Items.Add(model);` might end up calling that method but `itemsControl.ContainerFromDataContext(slideModel)` still returns null instead of a container of type `MyContainer. I am so confused. How can I fix this?? Thanks!

BTW in case it wasn't clear, im not trying to test ContainerFromDataContext method. I want to test another method but in order to test it, I need each item to have a container but I cant figure out how to do it for the test

Comment: You can't test this method. It is internally used by the [`ItemsGenerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator?view=netframework-4.8) when it realizes the items for display.

Comment: In general you don't need to test framework code. In general you can't test non public code.

Comment: is there a way i can make it think the window is displaying the item? some way of mocking it?

Comment: this is just for the sake of the question. Im not actually trying to test GetContainerForItemOverride(). Im testing some other methods. but for that, I need each item to have a container

Comment: The realization of items depends on the type of the `ItemsControl`. If it is a `ListBox` or a `ListView` items are generated the moment the items are realized. Due to virtualization this is when the items are prepared for display, when items are scrolled into view. If it is a custom `ItemsControl` that uses a `VirtualizingStackPanel` you can enable this behavior. If virtualization is not enabled then all items are generated at once as soon the `ItemsSource` is populated. You can create your own panel and manually generate the item containers. This is the closest you can get.

Comment: You  can disable virtualization by using the attached property `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"` for the test or alternatively  call `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem` and then realize it by bringing it into view `itemContainer.BringIntoView()`. This will trigger the generalization of the container. When virtualization is enabled all items that are not displayed doesn't have a container. Always get the container and then bring it into view.

Comment: Why do you need the item containers for your test? A unit test is not the way to test UI. And your code shouldn't depend on UI. Test must work without UI. This is because the view is handled by the framework. You can't mock the framework. It's not public.
The framework only exposes some entry points (e.g. declaring templates or styles or custom controls). A framework follows inversion of control (IoC). You don't use the framework. It uses you. That's why you can't mock framework internals.